# Script to change two dates

Tags: powershell

I tried changing the start and end date in the content of the file using the PowerShell script but it changes both dates to the same.

```
$path = "H:\oim\adcbsm007\adcbsm007.txt"
$path = "H:\oim\alps027\alps027.txt"
$word = "2016,01,28"
$replacement = "2016,01,29"
$text = get-content $path 
$newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement
$newText > $path
$path = "H:\oim\adcbm007\adcsm007.txt"
$path = "H:\oim\alps027\alps027.txt"
$word = "2016,01,29"
$replacement = "2016,01,30"
$text = get-content $path 
$newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement
$newText > $path
```

The content of the text file is something like this:

```
http://www.google.com="Global History"&customer=guest&password=guest&STARTTIME=2016,01,30,00,00,00&STOPTIME=2016,01,30,00,00,00&POINTSEVERY=15 min&GRAPHTYPE=excel
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the end date before the start date, otherwise the start date will be the same as the end date after the first replacement. Therefore the second replacement will change both start *and* end date to the new end date value. Also, if you want to do the replacement in several files you can't put the paths in the same variable, lest the second path replaces the first one. Use a list and a `foreach` loop (or something similar) instead.

```
$paths = 'H:\oim\adcbsm007\adcbsm007.txt', 'H:\oim\alps027\alps027.txt'

$startOld = '2016,01,28'
$startNew = '2016,01,29'
$endOld   = '2016,01,29'  # == $startNew
$endNew   = '2016,01,30'

foreach ($p in $paths) {
  (Get-Content $p) -replace $endOld, $endNew -replace $startOld, $startNew |
    Set-Content $p
}
```